# asp.net IIS 7.5 site bindings

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

i have an asp.net web page that is deployed to IIS 7.5 on my home computer. when i type in

```
http://192.168.1.11
```

into my browser it works fine. i would like to be able to type in the pc name as this would be simpler. i.e simply type in

```
http://computername
```

. this does not work though.
below are my binding settings which i am guessing is where the configuration problem is.
What should my settings be?
thanks
damo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the hosts file from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc folder and add an entry like below

```
192.168.1.11 computername
```

Comment: is it not possible to fix this within IIS?